# Is there a synonym of vacuity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can describe a set as empty or non-empty.  And I sometimes refer to the property of being empty as vacuity.  Is there a form of the word vacuity which means non-empty? non-vacuity seems wrong to me.

Comment: i would say vacuum

Comment: We use the locution [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) in "a statement that asserts that all members of the empty set have a certain property." But we refer to the *empty set* as "empty": why call it "vacuous set" ?

Comment: For example "in order to prove the vacuity of set H we recall Lemma 12".    I'm beginning to wonder whether I should just completely avoid this term as a useless word?

Answer (score 3):

The property of being empty is often called *emptyness*, and I have seen *nonemptyness* for the property of being nonempty.

By the way: Unfortunately there is no established sign for $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$, so that we have to express a positive fact using two negations. I sometimes write $A\!\supset\!\!\!\subset\! B$.

Comment: George Mackey invented a symmetrical symbol for this: a vertical line atop a small circle. He described it as "d for disjoint" with the round part of the d moved under the vertical for symmetry. There's probably at $LaTeX$ version.

Comment: I've been using the perpendicular symbol $A \perp B$ vs $A \not\perp B$ to mean disjoint/touching. And I just define that early in my paper among the notations.  However, some reviewers and smirked at the usage.  My notation does admittedly risk confusion if also used with the $\top$ and $\bot$ symbols.

Comment: Fine, except the spelling is emptiness. This follows a standard pattern in English: busy $\to$ business, holy $\to$ holiness, ready $\to$ readiness, usw.

Comment: Personally I like the parallel line symbol $A\parallel B$ to mean that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, but unfortunately nobody else does.

Answer (score 0):

I used *non-null* except there were too many complaints.
Another useful term is *multipoint*.